# How to get file size in template?

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I have model with CharField:

```
absolute_path_to_file = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And I want to display in template size of this file. How to do it? Filter?

```
{{ object.absolute_path_to_file|<????>size</????> }}
```

Comment: Why this field is CharField? It should be FileField

Comment: Sometimes the original data of a field may not be the file itself but a path to an external source of files, this may be the reason to use a CharField instead of a FileField, thought obviously is a design decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a way using the "custom filter" way:

```
import os
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def filesize(value):
    """Returns the filesize of the filename given in value"""
    return os.path.getsize(value)
```

That code should be in your django app in the folder "templatetags", for example in a python module named "utils.py". Then, to use the filter in a template this is an example:

```
{% load utils %}
{{ object.absolute_path_to_file|filesize }}
```

as well, you can anidate filters like this:

```
{{ object.absolute_path_to_file|filesize|filesizeformat }}
```

Comment: In Django 1.6 there is no need for a custom filter. You can use the file.size property on your object like so: `object.file.size|filesizeformat`

Comment: True, but for any reason, Nips says he has to use the absolute_path_to_file and he cannot change to a FileField

Comment: Thanks, but `'utils' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:..`

Answer (score 5):

Use [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) instead, then you can do

```
{{ object.absolute_path_to_file.size }}
```

Comment: I can't do this, must use path

Comment: ok, then just do it how the default file storage would do it. e.g. https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/files/storage.py#L249 - put a get_size method on your model.

Comment: James,  Nips must use a ˋpathˋ, so why do you mention ˋmodelˋ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `FileField`, then you can create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that takes the argument and tries to get the file size of that using the standard Python [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module.